# Missing parameter in a callback when I use a promise in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a simple request using `jQuery.get()` ([version jQuery 3.x](https://code.jquery.com)) with a promise passing two parameters (*id*, *errors*), so when I handle a `reject` with a callBack it seems like *errors* dissapears and when I use `console.log(errors)` it shows *undefined*.

What I'm trying to do is to make request to the [Star Wars api](https://swapi.co) (people section), so if I get 2 or more errors, I will break the recursion and show to a message in the console, but if there was just one error, it is supposed to continue with the next character.

I think I'm passing the parameters correctly, so can someone explain me where I'm mistaking?

Here is my  code:

```
const URL_API = 'https://swapi.co/api'
const PEOPLE_URL_API = '/people/'

const CHARACTERS = `${URL_API}${PEOPLE_URL_API}`
const options = { crossDomain: true }

let i = 0
let errors = 0

function getCharacterName(id, errors) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $
            .get(`${CHARACTERS}${id}`, options, (data) => {
                resolve(data)
            })
            .fail(() => reject(id, errors))
    })
}

// CallBack that will handle a possible error
const onError = (id, errors) => {
    console.log(id, errors)
    errors++
    if (errors < 3) {
        console.log(`We coudn't find the character ${id}`)
        recursive(i, errors)
    } else {
        console.log(`Too much errors, we can't continue`)
        console.log(errors)
    }
}

function recursive(i, errors) {
    i += 1
    getCharacterName(i, errors)
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(
                `I'm the character ${data.url
                    .substring(28)
                    .replace('/', '')}, my name is: ${data.name}`
            )
            console.log(i, errors)
            return recursive(i, errors)
        })
        .catch(onError)
}

recursive(i, errors)
```

So, after running this I get something like this in the console:

```
...
I'm the character 16, my name is: Jabba Desilijic Tiure
16 0
swapi.co/api/people/17/?crossDomain=true:1 GET https://swapi.co/api/people/17/?crossDomain=true 404
17 undefined
Too much errors, we can't continue
```

Comment: `reject` only has 1 parameter.

Comment: You were right, I changed it and everything works like a charm.